# Formcollection input values are empty in controller after ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I faced a problem with IE and FF; my application is working with Google Chrome.

I am binding a model to a view in ASP.NET MVC
I have a table row inside a form(and some other controls). I replace the table row's content on a button click with ajax call. After ajax call, if I submit form as shown below, I can not get formcollection inputs from controller method. There is no problem when I submit form before ajax call.

The js code to update table row's content:

```
function reloadCriteriaTable(unitID, criteriaCode, icerikRowSpan, icerikOnay) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ApproveParts/ReloadCriteria',
    data: { contentID: $('[name="contentID"]').val(), unitID: unitID, criteriaCode: criteriaCode, selectedValue: $("#validator_" + criteriaCode).val(), icerikRowSpan: icerikRowSpan, icerikOnay: icerikOnay },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        $('#tr_' + criteriaCode).replaceWith(data);
        $('#continueBtn').on('click', function () {
            $('#form_3').submit();
            return false;
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr + ' ' + status + " : " + error);
    }

});
}
```

Onclick function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnSubmitCriteria", function () {
    $('#form_3').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CourseCriteriaApprovment(FormCollection collection)
{

}
```

Comment: If it isn't working in IE and FF, odds are something is wrong with your client-side code.  Do you actually have `type` defined twice in your js?  Just an additional note, I wouldn't use a FormCollection, but a ViewModel to used for model binding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my real code I just have 'post' type; I pasted a wrong code block. For some reason, I do not want to use Viewmodel for this particular example. I just want to know why my formcollection is empty after making update to a table row, because if I do not make update, I get Formcollection properly from the controller after submit

Comment: Have you tried adding a break point on the form post to see what the debugger has to say?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by breakpoint on form post, I put breakpoint on my controller method, and it shows formcollection has no keys

Comment: Ok, so when are you actually calling the `reloadCriteriaTable` function?  Can you show us that code?

Comment: <select id="validator_@Model.Criteria.CriteriaCode" onchange="reloadCriteriaTable(@arguments)">

Comment: Now you only have one parameter being given to the function when it expects several.  Is there anyway you can post this to fiddler or something similar for a bigger picture of what you are working with?

Comment: No, sorry I did not put all parameters in my comment; I wrote @arguments instead of parameters, but I am sure they are alright. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Are the names of the elements getting set?  If there isn't a name on the form elements, the value won't be posted to the server.

Comment: <td style="display:none;">  <input type="hidden" name="criteriaCode" value="@Model.Criteria.CriteriaCode"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="unitID" value="@Model.UnitID"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="contentID" value="@ViewBag.ContentID"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="userProfile" value="@ViewBag.UserProfile" />
</td>

Comment: Names are given, as I said before; that updated table row is in a form with other controls. Formcollection comes correctly if I submit form directly. The problem occurs when I update table row inside the form; and after submit

Comment: It's hard to tell.  It sounds like it is submitting, just empty.  If that is the case, there must be something wrong with how you are creating the rows and the elements.  That is why it would be easier if you put all relevant client code in a fiddle or the like so we can see what you have and what could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with why you have mentioned both type "GET" and "POST" in your ajax call. Use "POST" only.

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ApproveParts/ReloadCriteria',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : return JSON.stringify({
            contentID: $('[name="contentID"]').val(),
            unitID: unitID,
            criteriaCode: criteriaCode,
            selectedValue: $("#validator_" + criteriaCode).val(),
            icerikRowSpan: icerikRowSpan,
            icerikOnay: icerikOnay
        });
});
```

In your controller action accept a class instead of FormCollection. Where the class has all properties defined same as the ones you are sending in your ajax call.

Comment: this is a good answer. who ever down voted this must be ediot...i saw the typye: post and get at the same time..i am upvoting for this..mate

Comment: I am not sure it will ever work with such url `ApproveParts/ReloadCriteria`, maybe only on main page (root level), try add extra `/` before

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it turns out I pasted the wrong code. In my code I just have 'post' as type. However, my problem is not about this ajax call; after I make this ajax call, the related table row is updated successfully. But after update if I submit the form, I get the Form collection empty in my controller.

Comment: Did you try adding the dataType and contentType fields and sending Json stringified data as shown above ?

Comment: Yes, I did; but instead of dataType:'json'; I tried dataType:'html' because I return a PartialViewResult.